# MSVC++ causing crash 0x80000003 on "Attach to Process"

Tags: visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-debugging, dll-injection

I'm injecting a dll into a third party program and debugging that dll with MSVC. I have been doing normally for some time until a recent update to the program now causes MSVC to crash each time I attach the debugger to the process while my dll is injected. My dll still runs normally, I just cannot debug it as attaching MSVC crashes the host program.

Event view shows this:

```
Faulting application name: SomeApp.exe, version: 1.0.1023.0, time stamp: 0x5109728a
Faulting module name: MyDLL.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5114e8b3
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x006f3b28
Faulting process id: 0x1b80
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce05f71b9d65a9
Faulting application path: C:\SomeApp.exe
Faulting module path: c:\programming\MyDLL\debug\MyDLL.dll
Report Id: 8762e85d-71ea-11e2-a78e-4495fc99073a
```

Is it possible the application now crashes itself if it detects a debugger attached? I'd like to note that my DLL is a legitimate serverside mod that does not violate any EULA/TOS or anything like that. It operates by replacing some Virtual Method Table (VMT) pointers for some objects in the host program, if that is relevant.

**Update** I can debug the OnAttach() portion of my dll with MSVC, however once the execution returns to the host process it crashes.

Comment: 0x80000003 is the debugger breakpoint exception.  It is supposed to be detected by the debugger, allowing it to gain control over the program.  Clearly your host is intercepting it first, treating it like an unhandled exception.  This may well be intentional, preventing debugging.  Or an oversight, talk to the programmer of the host app.

Comment: yes, this is done quite often to prevent ... well you from doing stuff like this.

Comment: Ah thanks for the insight. Like I said the developers have no problems with serverside mods, they actually endorse the one I've made however I can see this being used to prevent less honorable pursuits. I've already asked them about it since its now a possibility, however some things seem strange. Like the fact that I can debug simple injected dlls that don't modify any VMT pointers.