# Form crashes with Error code 0x80000003 on startup

Tags: vb.net, winforms, filenet-p8

I've run into issues when deploying a scanning application that uses IBM FileNet/P8 components.  On our normal dev and test environments, it starts without any issues. When we install on the client's environment, it fails at the startup splash screen.

The event log shows a cryptic (to me) error:

---

Faulting application name: {APP-NAME}.exe, version: 1.0.6717.26286, time stamp: 0x5b0688f9

Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.19160, time stamp: 
0x56bcd5c3

Exception code: 0x80000003

Fault offset: 0x0001338e

Faulting process id: 0x18d0

Faulting application start time: 0x01d3f345625afb81

Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86){PROGRAM-FOLDER}{APP-FOLDER}{APP-NAME}.exe

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll

Report Id: a13a97e5-5f38-11e8-a0e1-4437e67dd37e

---

Startup takes place in a module, modCommon.vb. 
The error seems to occur before any external components come into play.  Code used at the entry point (module's main() method):

```
    Dim clsConfig As New clsConfig
    Dim lngReturn As Integer
    Dim strErrMsg As String
    Dim blnConfigNotSet As Boolean

    If VB.Command() = "DEBUG" Then
        B_DEBUG = True
    End If

    blnConfigNotSet = False
    gudtConfig.CaptureFolder = Environ("COMPUTERNAME")

    frm_Start = New frmStart()
    frm_Start.Show()

    'Read config/ini files
    clsConfig.ReadConfigValues()
```

The code that comes after the last line, "clsConfig.ReadConfigValues()" is where the external components come into play. Usually they would display a login prompt, but as the crash happens before then I assume the application is not even getting that far.

To my eye, it looked like something must have been happening in clsConfig.ReadConfigValues(), but the code there does nothing exception take values from app.config.

Is anyone familiar with the error code/info above? Could it be an environmental issue?

### Quick Update

There is no sign of any debugger breaks in the code.   Will update again when I have this figured out.

Comment: "I assume..."  "To my eye, it looked like something must have been happening in..."  There are pretty simple ways for you to find out for sure.  Conversely, there's no way for us to find out those things for sure.  So, I recommend that you test it and figure that out for sure and try to isolate the problem.  As far as the error code goes, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773849/msvc-causing-crash-0x80000003-on-attach-to-process) page suggests that it has to do with the app requesting that a debugger be attached.  Maybe that helps you narrow it down.

Comment: It is the debugger break exception.  My crystal ball says that you forgot to remove a Debugger.Break() call in the code.

Comment: Is there any update regarding this issue? I just recently ran into this issue. Any input would be greatly appreciated.